# customize numbers in modelsummary estimate

Tags: r, modelsummary

I can use the following code

```
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

reg1 <- feols(mpg ~ cyl , data = mtcars)
reg2 <- feols(mpg ~ cyl + wt , data = mtcars)



modelsummary(
  list(reg1, reg2),
  fmt = NULL,
  estimate  = c("{round(estimate, 3)} [my number]"),
  statistic = "{round(std.error, 3)}",
  coef_omit = "Intercept",
  gof_omit = 'RMSE|AIC|BIC|R2|Std.Errors')
```

to display numbers in square brackets next to my estimates. However I want different numbers for each of the coefficient in each of the regressions. Can I do this? the `estimate` argument does not seem to accept vector or list inputs.

Comment: Could you say *exactly* what you mean by "I want different numbers for each of the coefficient in each of the regressions"?

Comment: @Vincent Ah, yes. I want different numbers across rows. I was wrong before, I can provide a vector to the estimate argument to get different numbers across columns/models but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to round numbers differently on a per-model basis. I don’t know any regression table package that can do that, but perhaps I’m missing something. That said, it is reasonably easy to do it semi-manually:

1. Export each model to a `modelsummary_list` object.
2. Round the numbers as you want.
3. Feed the `modelsummary_list` objects back to the `modelsummary()` function.

```r
library(modelsummary)
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, mtcars)

extract_and_round <- function(model, significant_digits = 2) {
    out <- modelsummary(model, output = "modelsummary_list")
    out$tidy$estimate <- format(out$tidy$estimate, digits = significant_digits)
    out$tidy$std.error <- format(out$tidy$std.error, digits = significant_digits)
    return(out)
}

models <- list(
    extract_and_round(mod1, 2),
    extract_and_round(mod2, 5)
)

# Feed the modelsummary_list objects back to modelsummary()
modelsummary(models, output = "markdown")
```

|  | (1) | (2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 34.661 | 34.184919 |
|  | (2.55) | (2.590778) |
| cyl | -1.587 | -1.227420 |
|  | (0.71) | (0.797276) |
| disp | -0.021 | -0.018838 |
|  | (0.01) | (0.010404) |
| hp |  | -0.014679 |
|  |  | (0.014651) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| R2 | 0.760 | 0.768 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.743 | 0.743 |
| AIC | 167.1 | 168.0 |
| BIC | 173.0 | 175.3 |
| Log.Lik. | -79.573 | -79.009 |
| F | 45.808 | 30.877 |
| RMSE | 2.91 | 2.86 |

Comment: This solved my problem. I was not aware of "modelsummary_list" argument.